# Trying to customise elements in visual composer / theme

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to edit some elements in a wordpress theme using visual composer.

The website is [tantricpleasure.co.uk](http://www.tantricpleasure.co.uk) and I am trying to change the testimonial tag from h5 to p

The theme uses visual composer so am struggling to find out where this is changed. Would appreciate some help :)

Comment: Can you give the url where you want to change the testimonial tag and which theme you are using?

Comment: the url is tantricpleasure.co.uk the testimonial tag is h5 class colored

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve this thing is by creating a child theme ([Have a look here](https://blog.visualcomposer.io/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme/)), and then modify the code as you want.